# Why does my window form look different when I run the program in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

My window.cs[design] looks good and how I want it to look but, once I run my program, it looks transparent, fuzzy, blurry, just awful! All my other windows look great and look like how they are suppose to look. I'm running on Windows 10. I don't know if this is computer issue or Visual Studio issue. I'm also using Visual Studio 2012

Here's how my design window is suppose to look

[Design view](http://s1064.photobucket.com/user/mavs1231/media/login_zps8vdkvjzi.png.html)

Here's how it looks once I execute the program

[After executing](http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u362/mavs1231/start_zpsyb20hml7.png)

Notice my textbox becomes transparent, the text becomes fuzzy/blurry. Is it my background image I used? Is it my settings?

I didn't post any code as this is just a design issue.

Here's my window code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class Room : Form
    {
        public Room()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PassText.PasswordChar = '*';
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            FloorSelection ss = new FloorSelection();
            ss.Show();

        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void EXIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\UserData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From dbo.[LOGIN] where username='" + UserText.Text + "' and Password ='" + PassText.Text + "'", con);
            FloorSelection ss = new FloorSelection();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select TYPE From dbo.[LOGIN] where username='" + UserText.Text + "' and Password ='" + PassText.Text + "'", con);
                FloorSelection ss1 = new FloorSelection();
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();


                sda1.Fill(dt1);
                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "FACULTY")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    FACULTY ff = new FACULTY();
                    ff.Show();
                }

                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "JANITOR")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    JANITOR jt = new JANITOR();
                    jt.Show();

                    if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "ADMINISTRATOR")
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        ADMINISTRATOR Admin = new ADMINISTRATOR();
                        Admin.Show();
                    }
                     else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("PLEASE CHECK YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label3.BackColor = Color.Empty;
        }

        private void UserText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PassText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your form's [`TransparencyKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx) property is set to white.  This means that every white pixel in your form will become transparent.  That seems to match the visual effect you are seeing.

To turn off the transparency, set the `TransparencyKey` to `Color.Empty` or select the property in the Visual Studio property window and press delete.

Comment: Huh, where's `TransparencyKey` located? And which setting in properties (name of the settings)

Comment: The setting is called "TransparencyKey" in the form's "Properties" window.  It's in the "Window Style" group of properties.  In your code, it would be in your `Room.Designer.cs` file

Comment: You're a lifesaver David! I'm presenting this today and you saved me big time!